# Combining GPS and vehicle data using for loops and if statements to summarise the distance run under various conditions, much like a excel SUMIF

Tags: python, performance, datetime

This is a follow-up to [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235337/nested-if-working-like-an-excel-sumif-for-two-unequal-lists-summing-the-distanc/235421#235421), code is significantly better thanks to comments. The problem is that now it takes 0.25 seconds to iterate 1 row of VehicleEvents through 95000 rows of GPS information. At this rate, with 370k rows of VehicleEvents, it will take me days and I was wondering if you can find a better way.

```
import csv
from openpyxl.utils.datetime import from_excel, to_ISO8601
import datetime
import timeit

tic = timeit.default_timer()

for x in range(1,2): # here the code will read from 34 csv files containing GPS informations into a list of lists
    csvfilepath = "GpsData{}.csv".format(x)
    # Here the gps data is loaded into list of lists gpsdata and the timestamp is converted to ISO8601
    with open(csvfilepath, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
        gpsdata = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
        for row in gpsdata:
            try:
                GpsTimestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[10], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
            except:
                GpsTimestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[10], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            row[10] = to_ISO8601(dt=GpsTimestamp)
    driving = 0
    idle = 0
    working = 0
    prev_job_end = ['2219-12-16T05:02:10Z']
    dists = [[], [], [], []] #this list of lists will capture the distances in the various states

    vhfilepath = "VehicleEvents.csv"
    # Capturing the headers in vehicle list
    with open(vhfilepath, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
    vehiclist = csv.DictReader(open(vhfilepath, "r"))
    for r in vehiclist:
        JobID = r["ID"]
        vehicle_no = r['Vhcl']
        mode = r['Mode']
        Engineon = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["Engineon"])))
        Engineoff = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["Engineoff"])))
        try:
            WorkStart = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["WorkStart"])))
            WorkEnd = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["WorkEnd"])))
        except:
            WorkStart = 2000
            WorkEnd = 2000
        try:
            ParkStart = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["ParkStart"])))
            ParkEnd = to_ISO8601(dt=from_excel(value=float(r["ParkEnd"])))
        except:
            ParkStart = 2000
            ParkEnd = 2000
        driving = idle = working = 0.0
        for i in range(len(gpsdata)): #I go through all rows of gps list
            if i % 930000 == 0 and i != 0: # Keeping track of the program
                toc = timeit.default_timer()
                print('processing algorithm: {}'.format(toc - tic))
                print('we are at row {}'.format(r["ï»¿ID"]))
            if vehicle_no == gpsdata[0][2] and Engineon <= gpsdata[i][10] <= Engineoff:  #I want to exclude if the vehicle was off at the gps timestamp
                c1 = gpsdata[i][10]
                c2 = gpsdata[i][8]
                if mode == 'DIS' :
                    if ParkStart <= c1 <= ParkEnd:
                        driving += float(c2)
                    if Engineon <= c1 <= ParkStart:
                        idle += float(c2)
                else:
                    if ParkEnd <= c1 <= Engineoff :
                        driving += float(c2)
                    if Engineon <= c1 <= ParkEnd:
                        idle += float(c2)
            elif vehicle_no == gpsdata[0][2] and Engineon >= gpsdata[i][10] >= prev_job_end[-1] :
                working += float(gpsdata[i][8])
        prev_job_end.append(Engineoff)
        toc = timeit.default_timer()
        dists[0].append(JobID)
        dists[1].append(driving)
        dists[2].append(idle)
        dists[3].append(working)
        driving = idle = working = 0.0
    with open("outfile{}.csv".format(x), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        outfile_writer.writerow((dists[0], dists[1], dists[2], dists[3])),
    tac = timeit.default_timer()
    print('exporting {}'.format(tac - toc))
```

Sample data:

```
GpsData =
AA,ddate,gps_id,latitude,longitude,speed,accuracy,bearing,distance,ip,Timestamp
6631060599,20191216,V001,50.94269749,71.30314074,0.61,16.687,120.2,4564.41,,12/16/2019 0:00
6631065030,20191216,V001,50.9437751,71.30016186,7.46,33.374,0,48356.2,,12/16/2019 4:31
6631065153,20191216,V001,50.94291191,71.30116373,4.04,24.272,31.6,12747.4,,12/16/2019 19:07
6631060271,20191217,V001,50.94866914,71.30378451,4.49,4.551,0,8368.56,,12/17/2019 17:10
6631060630,20191218,V001,50.94821482,71.30276768,5.16,50.061,27.7,28869.4,,12/18/2019 4:54
6631069096,20191219,V001,50.94534268,71.30259522,2.11,24.272,63.1,9506.68,,12/19/2019 2:55
6631059877,20191219,V001,50.94332513,71.30145316,1.72,10.619,32.4,14834.6,,12/19/2019 17:13
6631068956,20191219,V001,50.94716712,71.30282306,3.14,21.238,300.4,11038.9,,12/19/2019 21:33
6631067712,20191220,V002,50.93724855,71.29651212,9.71,18.204,206,96770.7,,12/20/2019 16:22
6631065674,20191221,V002,50.9467955,71.30202786,6.96,15.008,31.1,28784.4,,12/21/2019 0:07
6631061274,20191221,V002,50.94207924,71.29937677,7.86,30.34,194.3,43064.3,,12/21/2019 14:15
6631063673,20191221,V002,50.94591501,71.30136721,0.83,22.755,293,27036.3,,12/21/2019 18:37
6631064438,20191221,V002,50.94743564,71.30240991,0.56,39.442,259.7,3525.12,,12/21/2019 22:25
6631060673,20191222,V002,50.94580669,71.30148016,5.55,13.653,204.3,53280,,12/22/2019 3:26
6631068423,20191222,V002,50.91783065,71.28983391,6.24,28.823,2.5,42947.8,,12/22/2019 4:14
6631066879,20191222,V002,50.94432872,71.30065772,6.25,19.721,209.8,36728.9,,12/22/2019 11:44
6631068174,20191223,V002,50.93346341,71.29449935,9.26,25.789,28.8,42795.9,,12/23/2019 4:02

VehicleEvents = 
ID,Vhcl,Mode,CID,Engineon,Engineoff,WorkStart,WorkEnd,ParkStart,ParkEnd
85807835,V001,Manual,AAA5846129341,43815.08135,43815.08938,,,43815.07334,43815.08211
85809668,V001,Auto,AAA8022407504,43815.08938,43815.10535,43815.08938,43815.10535,43815.08938,43815.09535
85810976,V001,Auto,AAA0571518764,43815.10538,43815.11505,43815.10538,43815.11505,43815.10959,43815.11505
85813025,V001,Manual,AAA3189634914,43815.11506,43815.12703,43815.11506,43815.12703,43815.11506,43815.12303
85813028,V001,Manual,AAA1940741282,43815.11506,43815.12703,,,43815.11506,43815.12372
85815305,V001,Manual,AAA1894455904,43815.12705,43815.14505,43815.12705,43815.14692,43815.13366,43815.14505
85815467,V001,Auto,AAA9538532026,43815.12705,43815.14692,,,43815.13361,43815.14692
85821410,V001,Auto,AAA8391952906,43815.14696,43815.20984,43815.14696,43815.20984,43815.14696,43815.15206
85873358,V001,Manual,AAA4922964611,43815.72992,43815.74645,43815.72992,43815.74645,43815.73586,43815.74645
85875020,V001,Manual,AAA6039158858,43815.74646,43815.76461,43815.74646,43815.76601,43815.75975,43815.76461
85875137,V001,Manual,AAA7495366053,43815.74646,43815.76601,,,43815.75972,43815.76601
85877825,V001,Auto,AAA7638509608,43815.76602,43815.79272,43815.76602,43815.79429,43815.76602,43815.77079
85877942,V001,Auto,AAA1265572219,43815.76602,43815.79429,,,43815.76602,43815.76985
85879040,V001,Manual,AAA2968711840,43815.79431,43815.80431,43815.79431,43815.80431,43815.79431,43815.80127
85882028,V001,Manual,AAA7692514875,43815.80432,43815.83537,43815.80432,43815.83537,43815.80432,43815.82109
85884230,V001,Manual,AAA4674654439,43815.83538,43815.85745,43815.83538,43815.85745,43815.83538,43815.84685
85885460,V001,Auto,AAA8107186366,43815.85748,43815.86895,43815.85748,43815.86895,43815.86016,43815.86895
85885994,V001,Auto,AAA5796012701,43815.86916,43815.875,43815.86916,43815.875,43815.87164,43815.875
85886981,V001,Manual,AAA8719492664,43815.87502,43815.88547,43815.87502,43815.88547,43815.8795,43815.88547
85890116,V001,Manual,AAA2865936367,43815.88549,43815.91355,43815.88549,43815.91355,43815.89722,43815.9073
85890119,V001,Manual,AAA1887612592,43815.88549,43815.91355,,,43815.88549,43815.8972
85891310,V001,Auto,AAA1144467605,43815.91358,43815.92514,43815.91358,43815.92514,43815.91856,43815.92514
85892144,V001,Auto,AAA3719694551,43815.92516,43815.93397,43815.92516,43815.93523,43815.92922,43815.93397
```

Comment: Time has gone up from [3 seconds](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/235337/5) to 25? Bummer! I thought [Irnv' approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235359) most promising - have you given it a try? Results?

Comment: The data sample sucks for showing events for one vehicle, only. (For error tests, it would be essential to include at least one vehicle without events & vice-versa.)

Comment: `prev_job_end = ['2219-12-16T05:02:10Z']` is bound to give misleading timings on top of disappointing results.

Comment: @greybeard Mistyped, it's much faster. It's 250ms! Noted for the error testing. Can you think of alternative for **prev_job_end = ['2219-12-16T05:02:10Z']** ? I have tested it though and I see no logical problem.
About the approach I'll check now

Comment: It's almost two centuries 'till 2219, try `'2019-…'` (and adjust .25 as need arises).

Comment: Why do I read a zero in two occurrences of `gpsdata[0][2]`? Shouldn't that be `gps_data[i][GPS_ID]`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the performance characteristics of `csv.reader`, but is it possible you're getting sub-optimal I/O speeds because of how you're reading in the data?  What if you loaded it all into memory up front?

Comment: @SamStafford Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: @greybeard gpsdata[0][2] is indeed column GPS_ID and should not be zero

Comment: I don't complain the value to be zero, but the 1st index.

Comment: @greybeard yes you are right!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the code presented here notably more readable than the previous iteration - the main apparent difference is meaningful naming of variables (most not in snake_case, yet).

It looks like you want the results in one file per file of GpsData:
such should be specified explicitly, as should be whether output records *need to* stay in the order of jobs in the vehicle event file (with "prev"`job_end` taken care of).

You read the vehicle event file once per file of GpsData - if you don't expect it to change, don't:
read it once before even touching the GpsData. Into a `dict` with "Vhcl" as key (see below)

Given `csv.DictReader`'s ability to handle fieldnames, don't open code that.

You don't use the list of `prev_job_end`s: just keep one.

Why convert datetimes to ISO8601?

---

(running out of time.
Checking every combination of GPS×event record most likely kills your time performance, vectorised&filtered or not.
My current take: event list per vehicle, ordered by timestamp
got fed up with all the indexing and conversion, introduced classes. Work in progress:
classes & reading vehicles

```
#@functools.total_ordering()
class Gps:
    def __init__(self, distance, timestamp):
        self.distance = distance
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        return "Gps(" + str(self.distance) + ", " + str(self.timestamp) + ')'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp == other.timestamp

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp < other.timestamp

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp <= other.timestamp

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp >= other.timestamp

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp > other.timestamp


class Vehicle_event:
    def __init__(self, mode, engine_on, engine_off,
                 work_start, work_end, park_start, park_end):
        self.mode = mode
        self.engine_on = engine_on
        self.engine_off = engine_off
        self.work_start = work_start
        self.work_end = work_end
        self.park_start = park_start
        self.park_end = park_end

    def __str__(self):
        return '<'+self.mode+", ".join(("",
            str(self.engine_on), str(self.engine_off),
            str(self.work_start), str(self.work_end),
            str(self.park_start), str(self.park_end)))+'>'

class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, vid):
        self.id = vid
        self.events = []
        self.gps = []
```

reading vehicle events:

```
EVENTDEFAULT = 2000  # whatever is appropriate


def event2timestamp(index, row, default=None):
    if default:
        try:
            return from_excel(float(row[index]  # .strip()
                                    )).timestamp()
        except:
            return default
    return from_excel(float(row[index]  # .strip()
                            )).timestamp()


def read_records(csv_path, key_name):
    """ Read records from the CSV file named into lists that are values of a
        dict keyed by the values of column key_name.
        Return this directory.
    """
    with open(csv_path, "r") as f:
        records = dict()    # defaultdict(list)
        rows = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(rows)
        KEY_INDEX = header.index(key_name)
        # JOB_ID = header.index("ID")
        # VEHICLE_NO = header.index('Vhcl')
        MODE = header.index('Mode')
        ENGINE_ON = header.index("Engineon")
        ENGINE_OFF = header.index("Engineoff")
        WORK_START = header.index("WorkStart")
        WORK_END = header.index("WorkEnd")
        PARK_START = header.index("ParkStart")
        PARK_END = header.index("ParkEnd")
        for row in rows:
            vid = row[KEY_INDEX]
            vehicle = records.get(vid)
            if None is vehicle:
                vehicle = Vehicle(vid)
                records[vid] = vehicle
            vehicle.events.append(Vehicle_event(
                row[MODE],
                event2timestamp(ENGINE_ON, row),
                event2timestamp(ENGINE_OFF, row),
                event2timestamp(WORK_START, row, EVENTDEFAULT),
                event2timestamp(WORK_END, row, EVENTDEFAULT),
                event2timestamp(PARK_START, row, EVENTDEFAULT),
                event2timestamp(PARK_END, row, EVENTDEFAULT)))
    return records


def read_vehicle_events():
    return read_records("VehicleEvents.csv", 'Vhcl')


vehicles = read_vehicle_events()
```

outermost loop over GPS files, inner loops over vehicles and events:

```
for x in range(1, 2):  # 34): # handle CSV files containing GPS records
    csvfilepath = "GpsData{}.csv".format(x)
    # Here the GPS data is appended to lists of Gps
    with open(csvfilepath, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
        COLUMNS = len(headers)
        ID = headers.index('gps_id')
        DISTANCE = headers.index('distance')
        TIMESTAMP = headers.index('Timestamp')
        eventless = defaultdict(int)
        for rec in reader:
            if len(rec) < COLUMNS:
                continue
            vid = rec[ID]
            vehicle = vehicles.get(vid)
            if None is vehicle:
                eventless[vid] += 1
            else:
                timestamp = rec[TIMESTAMP]
                try:
                    gps_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
                except:
                    gps_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                vehicle.gps.append(Gps(float(rec[DISTANCE]),
                                       gps_timestamp.timestamp()))

    print(eventless)

    dists = [[]]*4  # distances in the various states

    for vehicle in vehicles.values():
        vehicle.gps = sorted(vehicle.gps)
        prev_job_end = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 15, 5, 2, 10).timestamp()

        driving = idle = working = 0.0
        first, beyond = 0, len(vehicle.gps)

        for job in vehicle.events:
            first = bisect_left(vehicle.gps, Gps(0, prev_job_end), 0,  # first?
                                beyond)
            beyond = bisect_right(vehicle.gps, Gps(0, job.engine_off), first)
            for g in range(first, beyond):  # all Gps from previous Engineoff to current
                gps = vehicle.gps[g]
                timestamp = gps.timestamp
                distance = gps.distance
                if timestamp < job.engine_on:
                    if prev_job_end <= timestamp:
                        working += distance
                elif job.mode == 'DIS':
                    if timestamp <= job.park_start:
                        idle += distance
                    elif timestamp <= job.park_end:
                        driving += distance
                else:
                    if job.park_end <= timestamp:
                        driving += distance
                    else:
                        idle += distance
        prev_job_end = job.engine_off
        vehicle.events.clear()

        dists[0].append(vehicle.id)
        dists[1].append(driving)
        dists[2].append(idle)
        dists[3].append(working)
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    with open("outfile{}.csv".format(x), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"',
                                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        outfile_writer.writerow(dists)
    tac = timeit.default_timer()
    print('exporting {}'.format(tac - toc))
```

)

Comment: This implementation takes 6.6 seconds per row, however since the rows are sorted, this may change
I did not manage to use the bisect functions because I didn't understand the documentation
However I did understand what you said and made an if -> continue which cut processing time a lot
I convert to ISO8601 because I know not of a better way to compare datetimes

I think I will let it run for a few hours and see if it gets faster, then compare with the previous one

Answer (score 2):

With 90k gps records and 370k vehicle records, the inner loop of the current code runs **33.3 Billion** times.  To get significant speed ups will require a different approach.

I would suggest converting everything to an event: gps event, engineon event, engineoff event, and so on.  Put it all into a big queue (list) and sort it by time stamp.  It looks like the gps data and vehicle events are already sorted, or nearly so.  On my machine, it takes less than a second to sort a million records.  Could use a heap instead of sorting.

Then loop through the events once, updating the status of the vehicles and jobs, and collecting data, as you go.